# Code works correctly if compiled with a Makefile, it crashes if compiled with XCode

Tags: c++, c++11, xcode4, makefile, ofstream

I'm experiencing a strange problem in one of my projects. My code base depends on an external library, which contains a class named `Dataset`. The `Dataset` class privately inherits from `std::vector<Sample>` (where `Sample` is another custom class defined in the library).

Moreover, such a class exposes a `Save` member function in order to serialize the data composing the data set into a text file. The `Save` member function is defined as follows:

```
inline void Dataset::Save(string filename, ModalityType modality)
{
    ofstream log_file;
    if (modality == OVERWRITE) {
        log_file.open(filename.c_str());
    } else {
        log_file.open(filename.c_str(), ios::out | ios::app);
    }
    if (log_file.is_open()) {
        log_file << *(this);
    }
    log_file.close();
}

ofstream& operator<< (ofstream& out, Dataset& ds)
{
    unsigned int size = ds.size();
    unsigned int input_size = ds.GetInputSize();
    unsigned int output_size = ds.GetOutputSize();
    out << input_size << " " << output_size << endl;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        Sample* s = ds[i];
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < input_size; j++) {
            out << s->GetInput(j) << " ";
        }
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < output_size; j++) {
            out << s->GetOutput(j) << " ";
        }
        out << endl;
    }

    return out;
}
```

Both my code and the external library have been compiled under OS X 10.8.2 with clang 4.2 and flags `-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++`. I need to do so, since my code base uses several C++11 facilities (e.g., `random`). Moreover, the library itself depends on boost, which in turn has been compiled with clang and C++11 support.

Everything compiles and works as expected by using the following Makefile:

```
CXX = clang++
CXXDIALECT = -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++
DEFS = -DBOOST_NO_CXX11_NUMERIC_LIMITS
INCLUDE_DIRS = -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/opt/local/include
LIB_DIRS = -L/usr/local/lib -L/opt/local/lib 
LIBS = -lfitted -lgsl -lgslcblas -lboost_thread -lboost_program_options -lboost_regex -lboost_system
CINCLUDE = $(INCLUDE_DIRS)
CXXFLAGS = -Os $(CXXDIALECT) $(CINCLUDE) $(DEFS)

tests := main.cpp
sources := $(filter-out $(tests), $(wildcard *.cpp))
objects :=  $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(sources))

main: $(objects)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $@.cpp $(objects) $(LIBS) $(LIB_DIRS) -v

%.o : %.cpp
    $(CXX) -c $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

where `libfitted` is the name of the external library.

Nevertheless, I'm developing my code under XCode 4.6.2. The problem is that everytime I try run/debug the code in XCode, the `Dataset.save` member function triggers the following error:

[image: EXC_BAD_ACCESS]

and an empty `dataset.txt` file is created on disk. Here's a couple of screenshots of the stack trace:

[image: stack trace1]
[image: stack trace2]

Click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bS8OS.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bS8OS.png) to view them in full size.

As reported in the screenshots, the problem *seems* to be in the `ofstream.flush()` member function.
Finally, I report the output of both [make](http://pastebin.com/LuPCZ9Wc) and [xcodebuild](http://pastebin.com/JbRrKDcL)

I really can't figure out why the same code, with the same compiler and libraries, executes correctly if compiled with the afore-mentioned Makefile, while it is not working if executed in XCode.

**UPDATE #1:** I just noticed that the code is debuggable in XCode (although not runnable) if I use as debugger GDB instead of LLDB, i.e., `Dataset.save` does not trigger the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.

**UPDATE #2:** I recompiled the library with the `-g -O0` flags so as to preserve debug symbols. The problem is that everytime a `ofstream` object is initialized in a `Dataset`'s member function, the `this` pointer of the `Dataset` instance becomes `NULL`, i.e., the `Dataset` object is nullified. Consequently, each attempt to access any data member within the member function results in a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. This is one of the weirdest thing I've ever seen. Any idea on why this is happening?

Thanks.

Comment: When code that runs when compiled in one compiler crashes when compiled with another, it's usually due to some undefined behavior. If you enable more compiler warnings, do you get any compiler warnings? They are usually a good indicator of (some) undefined behavior.

Comment: It could also be that you have two versions of some source file, one that is used in the makefile, and another in the Xcode project, and that file contains some error in one of the versions.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The Makefile uses the same compiler (clang) and user-defined flags (`-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++`) as XCode. Moreover, the source files are the same (I simply run the Makefile in the folder where the source files are stored). Regarding the warnings, in XCode many warning flags are active by default, and indeed I obtain several warnings. Nevertheless, all  warning are about the boost library, rather than the classes composing the `libfitted` library per se. For the sake of completeness, I will add the output of both `make` and `xcodebuild`

Comment: I note that your Makefile version uses default (not hidden) visibility and that your Xcode build is using hidden visibility.  I don't know that this difference is the problem, but it is the next thing I recommend investigating.  In your Xcode project, try setting both -fvisibility=default and turning off -fvisibility-inlines-hidden.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I modified both flags accordingly to your suggestion. Unfortunately, it still does not work. I will add a second screenshot of the stack trace so as to highlight that most probably the error occurs in the `ofstream.flush()` member function

Comment: Is it guaranteed that each `Sample` has the same input and output sizes on a given `Dataset`?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Each `Sample` object is instantiated as: `Sample* s = new Sample(new Tuple(input_size), new Tuple(output_size));`, where `Tuple` is yet another custom class defined in the library. The variables `input_size` and `output_size` are initialized with a constant value before populating the `Dataset` object. However, the code should work even in case of non-constant `output_size` and `input_size` values, since the `operator<<` free function simply serializes data on a text file, where in principle each row can have a different length wrt. the others.

Comment: dataset.txt is the problem... where is it located?

Comment: `dataset.txt` is saved in the same directory as the executable.

Comment: I updated the question with an important observation.

Comment: Re your Update #2: You can see from your stack trace that in the call to `ds.Save("dataset.txt")`, the reference `ds` is NULL (i.e., you enter the `Save` function with `%rdi = 0`). Can you reduce your program to a [short test case](http://sscce.org) that still reproduces the problem? For example, remove everything from your `main()` routine except the call to `ds.Save()`.

Comment: The std::vector<...> class is not designed to be used as a base class. Using it as such leads to undefined behaviour (because of the lack of a virtual destructor, at least)

I don't know if this is the problem that you are facing, but undefined behaviour might well lead to this :) .

Answer (score 1):

The std::vector<...> class is not designed to be used as a base class. Using it as such leads to undefined behaviour (because of the lack of a virtual destructor, at least).

Item 35 in C++ Coding Standards (Sutter, Alexandrescu), named

> Avoid inheriting from classes that were not designed to be base
>   classes.

might well be of help here.

Item 7 of Effective C++ (Meyers) discuss the issue with this example:

```
class SpecialString: public std::string{
...
}
```

> At first glance, this may look innocuous, but if anywhere in an
>   application you somehow convert a pointer-to-SpecialString into a
>   pointer-to-string and you then use delete on the string pointer, you
>   are instantly transported to the realm of undefined behavior.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You are right when you say that inheriting from `std::vector` should be avoided. However, I'm privately inheriting from `std::vector`, meaning that I'm modeling a "implemented-in-terms-of" relationship, rather than a "is-a" relationship.

Comment: Yes, I noticed. The private inheritance solves the "design" problem of using an "is-a" relationship when it is not needed. On the other hand, because std::vector defines a non-virtual destructor, there is a technical problem which leads to undefined behaviour whenever you derive from it.

Comment: AFAIK, privately inheriting from std::vector solves also the technical problem, since private inheritance is the same as containment.

Comment: I'm not aware of anything like that. Can you point me out to some reference? It would be very interesting to know, to me at least.

Comment: It may be better to rephrase my last statement as follows: private inheritance acts as composition. Only `Dataset` member functions can bind a `Dataset` object to a `std::vector` pointer. From the outside it is not possible to obtain a pointer to `std::vector` starting from a pointer of type `Dataset`. When the `Dataset` object is destroyed, the `Dataset` destructor will be called first, followed by the `std::vector` destructor. Here's a comparison between the two approaches: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/priv-inherit-like-compos.html

Comment: Ok, I can see your point. Technically, nothing impedes you to do the conversion+delete from inside the class.

So basically, with all probability this is not the problem showing up in your code.